# How toggle repeated angular directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

First I'm not sure how to search for this, so I'm sorry if there's already a answering for that.

Well...

I have an directive that is calling in every repeated item on my list.

Follow the code:

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in data.items">
    <md-button aria-label="Seguir" class="md-icon-button" ng-click="toggle()">
        <ng-md-icon icon="add_circle"></ng-md-icon>
    </md-button>
    <playlist-add genre="data.genre.slug" playlist="item.slug" bn-good-if="showMenu"></playlist-add>
</div>
```

My directive (not big deal)

```
app.directive('playlistAdd', function(PlaylistService) {
  return {
    templateUrl: BaseHelper.paths.view('playlist/add'),
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

      $scope.showMenu = false;

      $scope.toggle = function() {
        $scope.showMenu = !$scope.showMenu;        
      };

    }
  };
})
```

My controller (also nothing new)

```
app.controller('PlaylistTrendingCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.showMenu = false;

  $scope.toggle = function() {
    $scope.showMenu = !$scope.showMenu;
  };
```

With this code, I have two options:

1. Use just like that and open all the **menu element** at once.
2. Change the `$scope.showMenu` and `$scope.toggle` into my directive, where the **menu element** would open one by one, but once always opened.

The most close I got to my need was the option 2, but I need close one to open other, something [like this](http://codepen.io/rochapablo/pen/qZqJXo)

So, anyone?

Thanks.

Comment: can you clarify the result you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this [JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/leliti/edit?html,js,console,output) . This is the quickest solution I could come up with according to your requirements (the link you provided). Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not sure if the way I did is the best approach, but your example worked! Because the ***repeat items*** came from server, I had to re-read and re-write adding the ```.expanded```